# PinesScript timing behaving strangely

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Can someone please explain me why is this indicator in PineScript v5 firing alert immediately after attaching the alert to the chart?

Attaching this way:

```
1. Pine Editor / Save
2. Pine Editor / Add to chart
3. Chart / <indicator_name> / ... / Add alert on <indicator_name>
    popup window / condition: Any alert() function call / Create
4. Alerts log -> alert is immediately fired here
```

PineScript code:

```
next_min_border_to_set = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute(time) + 1, 0)
var next_minute_border = timestamp(year, month, dayofmonth, hour, minute(time) + 2, 0)
if time >= next_minute_border
    next_minute_border := next_min_border_to_set

    string data = calculate(...)
    alert(data)
```

By my understanding this should happen:

1. `next_minute_border_to_set` is calculated and is assigned to the variable as current tick's local variable
2. `var next_minute_border` will only be set once, containing the value calculated during the processing the very first tick
3. while processing the first tick, the `time` in `line#3` should be still smaller than the calculated `next_minute_border` variable which has `current minute + 2` value, so the script should wait form 1 to 2 minutes to reassign the `next_minute_border` variable (until the current time is not bigger than the previously calculated one)

**BUT this is not happening**
The alert immediately fires once the alert is created.

**Questions**

- why is this happening?
- what am I missing here?
- how can I write an indicator, where the alert will wait for the next candle, and will not fire immediately and the following alerts can happen only once per candle as well?

Comment: What is your end goal here? And on what timeframe(s) do you want to use this?

Comment: @vitruvius I want to use it on M1, and I've defined the end goal: `an indicator, where the alert will wait for the next candle, and will not fire immediately and the following alerts can happen only once per candle`